# Using a helper method to handle awaiting DB connections

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I have a class which needs to connect to MongoDB. We can't use `await` inside a constructor so I went with doing the connection async in the constructor, then having a helper method that would `await` this:

```
export class DB {
  private readonly connection: Promise<MongoClient>

  constructor() {
    // Connect async to the database. The `collection` method handles awaiting the promise
    this.connection = new Mongo().connect()
  }

  // Helper method to await the mongo connection, since we can't await inside a constructor
  private readonly collection = async (): Promise<Collection<MyCollection>> => {
    const conn = await this.connection
    return conn.db('db').collection('coll') as Collection<MyCollection>
  }
  ...
}
```

It seems like a good workaround to me, however, when I want to actually use the collection, it looks a bit messy:

```
public getById = async (id: string): Promise<Thing | null> => {
    const doc = await (await this.collection()).find(id)
```

I'm not a fan of the double await. I could split it up a bit:

```
const col = await this.collection()
const doc = await col.find(id)
```

But I'm not a fan of that either. By itself, it isn't too bad. However, this will be repeated in each method which means a lot of duplication and smell.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I know I could have an `init()` function which handles the `await` and connection to Mongo. However, this class is called within the constructor of another class, which won't be able to `await` the `init` method, so I would need to change that to have an `init` method and bubble that style up as far as I need to.

Comment: You could inject the connection into `DB` instead of creating and awaiting it in the constructor.

Comment: I had that thought too, which would be ideal. However, I am using Restify and this isn't the entry point, which would mean injecting the connection in to the controller and passing that off to each class until it reaches the DB class

Comment: `const doc = await this.collection().then(col => col.find(id));` looks a little more fluent...